# Show two functions having nonzero Wronskian implies they are solution to some differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose there exists $y_1,y_2 \in C^2$ defined on an interval I such that the Wronskian : $$ y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2$$ has no zeros in I.

Show that this implies there exists continuous functions $f, g$ such that $y_1, y_2$ are solutions to the differentiable equation: $$y''(x)+y'(x)f(x)+y(x)g(x)=0$$
I'm really at a loss here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider
$$ \eqalign{y_1''(x) + y_1'(x) f(x) + y_1(x) g(x) &= 0\cr
y_2''(x) + y_2'(x) f(x) + y_2(x) g(x) &= 0\cr}$$
as a system of two linear equations in the unknowns $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Comment: Ah, that's embarrassingly simple.